# MvvmCross Bind command to <include> toolbar

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross, xamarin.forms

I want to bind commands to my toolbars' items. Is it possible?
I have tried this but it's still doesn't work https://stackoverflow.com/a/21936542/6160208

**Toolbar.axml**

```
<Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="85dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/searchImageButton"
            android:layout_marginLeft="290dp"
            local:MvxBind="Click DoSearchCommand"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
```

**MainView.axml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
          <include
              layout="@layout/toolbar" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
    private MvxCommand _searchCommand;
    public System.Windows.Input.ICommand SearchCommand
    {
        get
        {
            _searchCommand = _searchCommand ?? new MvxCommand(DoSearchCommand);
            return _searchCommand;
        }
    }
    private void DoSearchCommand()
    {
        ShowViewModel<SearchViewModel>();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bind to `DoSearchCommand` but that is the method. You should bind to `SearchCommand`

```
local:MvxBind="Click SearchCommand"
```

As improvement you could use a `IMvxCommand` instead of a `ICommand` too, and add the ShowViewModel as lambda.

```
private MvxCommand _searchCommand;
    public IMvxCommand SearchCommand
    {
        get
        {
            _searchCommand = _searchCommand ?? new MvxCommand(() => ShowViewModel<SearchViewModel>());
            return _searchCommand;
        }
    }
```